# Unable to use SelectMany to fetch parent property in DocumentDb LINQ query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have a nested document structure like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "parent1",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "child1",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "id": "child2",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "id": "child3",
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "parent2",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "child4",
        "foo": "bar"
      },
      {
        "id": "child5",
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am able to write the following query in SQL syntax:

```
SELECT child, parent.id
FROM parent
JOIN child in parent.children
```

This gets me the following result:

```
[
  {
    "child": {
      "id": "child1",
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "id": "parent1"
  },
 ...
]
```

I wrote a similar query in LINQ using SelectMany clause as follows, but it throws an error stating SelectMany can have only 2 arguments.

```
collection.SelectMany(
    parent => parent.children,
    (parent, child) => new { child, parent.id });
```

Comment: Your query looks quite OK to me. Is it the O-R mapper that doesn't understand this `SelectMany` overload? Exact error message? In case of yes, the answer of dasblinkenlight could solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "push" the second lambda inside the first lambda with a nested `Select`, like this:

```
collection.SelectMany(
    parent => parent.children.Select(child => new {
        Child = child
    ,   ParentId = parent.id
    })
);
```

Comment: This is one of those situations where you google something for a long period of time and then stumble upon the answer almost randomly